# Prove that this function is injective

Tags: functions, proof-verification

I need to prove that this function is injective:

$$f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$$

$$f: (x, y) \to (2y-1)(2^{x-1})$$

Sadly, I'm stumbling over the algebra. Here is what I have so far:

Suppose $f(x, y) = f(a, b)$.

We want to show that $x = a$ and $y = b$.

$$(2y-1)(2^{x-1}) = (2b-1)(2^{a-1})$$

$$(2y-1)\dfrac{(2^{x})}{-2} = (2b-1)\dfrac{(2^a)}{-2}$$

At this point I got stuck, and I don't know how to get it to a place where I can solve and conclude that $x = a$ and $y = b$.

Comment: Yes. I'll add that to the problem to be clear.

Comment: Your math notation style is weird.  I cleaned up lots of things like 2$y$-1 instead of $2y-1$ and $\mathbb N$x$\mathbb N$ instead of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* the feature of natural numbers that this function captures is that every natural number can be written *uniquely* as the product of an odd number and a power of $2$.

I assume that $f: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N $.

Comment: Since each number can be written unique as the product of an odd number and a power of two, is that enough to justify pulling the equation apart and saying that (2y-1) must equal (2b-1) and (2^x)/-2 must equal (2^a)/-2? Thanks btw.

Comment: @user3025403, no, that's what you're trying to prove. Just use that $2$ cannot divide an odd number.

Comment: I'm sorry @lhf, but I don't understand how the fact that 2 cannot divide an odd number leads to the justification above or that this function is injective.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2y-1)2^{x-1}= (2b-1)2^{a-1}$$

If $x\ne a$ then either $x>a$ or $x<a$.  Just call whichever one is bigger $a$, so that $x<a$.

Divide both sides by $2$, and repeat $x-1$ times.  For example, say $(2y-1)2^{x-1}=1344$. Dividing by $2$ gives $672$; dividing by $2$ again gives $336$; dividing by $2$ again gives $168$; dividing by $2$ again gives $84$; dividing by $2$ again gives $42$; dividing by $2$ again gives $21$, an odd number, so $2y-1=21$ and $y=11$.

You should also get $21$ on the right side after all those divisions by $2$.  But you get $(2b-1)2^{a-x}$.  Since $a>x$, that's an even number, so it can't be $21$.

Hence $a$ must be equal to $x$, so $2y-1=2b-1$, and finally $y=b$.